# Relative redirect breaks twitter client

Tags: bug, status-completed

This url: `http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/165971?atw=1` redirects to , `/questions/165971/how-is-architectural-design-done-in-an-agile-environment`

According to [the http spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) , this should be:

> The field value consists of a single absolute URI.

My twitter client detects the redirect, and opens the browser at the redirected url, without the host, so the page doesn't load.

Comment: *Your* Twitter client?

Comment: I mean the client I use (Tweetcaster)

Comment: Eugh, you've got me updating *my* websites now, I've always used relative as well :P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

A fix for this will go out in the next build.